# Gravity Forms - Show link after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a link set with `display: none` with the URL of a file that my users can download after correct submission of a Gravity Form. The things is I only want to show this link if submission was successfull.

The only event I have found so far is `gform_post_render`, but it is triggered each time the form is loaded, even if there was an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when someone successfully submits a form gravity form show any success message ? if yes hook onto that, (using jquery or natively in wordpress php)

Comment: Yes. It does show a success message. But I don't know to which event I have to hook! There is no page reload in this process, so it has to be jQuery, not PHP

Comment: you can try on change event on parent div of that message and check if success message class exists

Comment: this is a good idea. I will try it on monday. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I found the appropriate event:

```
$(document).bind('gform_confirmation_loaded', function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```